# How can I create a new Role with openstack4j?

Tags: java, eclipse, identity, roles, openstack

I'm developing an eclipse project by exploiting openstack4j APIs (v. 2.0.9). I need to create a new role so I tried (after V2 authentication) to use a Builder like Users creation:

```
public void role_create(String name) { 
   Role role = os.identity().roles().create(Builders.role().name(name).build());
}
```

When I noticed the error

> The method create(String) in the type RoleService is not applicable
>   for the arguments (Role)

I supposed I just had to pass the 'name' parameter to the create method:

```
public void role_create(String name) {
    Role role = os.identity().roles().create(name);
}
```

Anyway when I run the program on the server I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" ServerResponseException{message=Internal
>   Server Error, status=500, status-code=INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR} at
>   org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExceptionHandler.mapException(HttpExceptionHandler.java:40)
>   at
>   org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExceptionHandler.mapException(HttpExceptionHandler.java:23)
>   at
>   org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpEntityHandler.handle(HttpEntityHandler.java:50)
>   at
>   org.openstack4j.connectors.okhttp.HttpResponseImpl.getEntity(HttpResponseImpl.java:69)
>   at
>   org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:189)
>   at
>   org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:183)
>   at
>   org.openstack4j.openstack.identity.internal.RoleServiceImpl.create(RoleServiceImpl.java:121)
>   at openstack.Identity.role_create(Identity.java:75) at
>   openstack.openstackTest.main(openstackTest.java:21)

When I create users I use Builders to create an User object and pass it to the create method. The create method for roles does not want a Role object but a String, that's why I just tried to pass the 'name' string. When the exception occurs I read the RoleServiceImpl.java file to see the create method. That's the result:

```
@Override
public Role create(String name) {       
    checkNotNull(name);         
    return post(KeystoneRole.class, 
  uri("/OS-SADM/roles")).entity(KeystoneRole.builder().name(name).build()).execute();   
}
```

So it seems the Builder is implemented! Can anyone help me to solve this problem and create a new Role?

Best regards,
Fabio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! OpenStack V2 needs just the name of the role to crete it, but the version of Openstack4j I used automatically embedded in the request also the "enabled" parameter. That's why I got an exception. The bug was fixed in the latest version of the library (2.20)